# link to edit a post has empty target

Tags: posts, dashboard, post-editor

I open the admin dashboard and navigate to "Posts"
I see the normal list of my posts
On some post I can click and the editor opens (everything is normal)
BUT:
On some post the link, which should be something like (wp-admin/post.php/post=[ID]&action=edit... ), hast just an empty target.
I can see the link, but the target is jus empty (href="")
I can't find a common ground of these faulty posts.
When I set my rights to administrator is works fine, but even if I use the same rights as other users I still get these empty edit-link-targets.

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I just found some kind of workaround.

I set the right "edit options" for this user.

To be honest I do not know what this right means, but the user is now able to edit all the posts - so the links now have a valid target (href)
Strange behaviour. 
Somebdoy can explain this?